# Forward a shapekey name to a "set" def

Tags: python, scripting, shape-keys

Python complete beginner here. 
I struggled hard to find the way to animate shapekeys from a panel slider.
I almost got it. It works but only when I write the name of the shapekey myself (lines 8 and 12).
I want to apply the "set_shapekeys" to many shapekeys so I would like to know how to pass the name of my shapekey in something like "obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks[keyname] but it doesn't work.
Hope someone can help me. 
Thanks in advance.

````
import bpy
from bpy.types import Panel, Operator
from bpy.props import FloatProperty
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector

def set_shapekey(self, value) :
    obj = bpy.data.objects['foo']
    shape_key = obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks["lobh"] #line 8
    keys = obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks.keys()
    shape_key_index = keys.index(shape_key.name)
    obj.active_shape_key_index = shape_key_index    
    bpy.data.shape_keys["Key"].key_blocks["lobh"].value = value  #line 12

class FOO_PT_panel_2(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "foo settings"
    bl_category = "foo"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_options = {"DEFAULT_CLOSED"}

    def draw(self, context):
        row = layout.row()
        obj = bpy.data.objects['foo']
        split=layout.split()
        col=split.column(align=True)
        if obj is not None:
            col.prop(obj, 'myFloatlobh', slider=True)

        obj = bpy.data.objects['foo']
        #split=layout.split()
        #col=split.column(align=True)

        if obj is not None:
            col.prop(obj, 'myFloatlobw', slider=True)

        obj = bpy.data.objects['foo']
        #split=layout.split()
        #col=split.column(align=True)

        if obj is not None:
            col.prop(obj, 'myFloatlobd', slider=True)

#floatproperty
bpy.types.Object.myFloatlobh = FloatProperty(name = "Foomax", min = 0, max = 1, soft_min=0, soft_max=1, default=0, set = set_shapekey)
bpy.types.Object.myFloatlobw = FloatProperty(name = "Foomin", min = 0, max = 1, soft_min=0, soft_max=1, default=0, set = set_shapekey)         
bpy.types.Object.myFloatlobd = FloatProperty(name = "Foothick", min = 0, max = 1, soft_min=0, soft_max=1, default=0, set = set_shapekey)         

classes = (FOO_PT_panel_2,)
def register(): 
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)

def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```
````

Comment: Hi. When you say "it doesn't work", what happens? Do you get error messages in the console?

Comment: Hey, what is that, Duarte Farrajota Ramos ? A good moderator who wants to help a beginner ? You deleted my post because  I gave an ansswer instead of a comment ! It is my first post and you ban me like a policeman, a little chief overusing his powers ? I have a problem, I thought Stack Exchange would be a nice way to learn Python. Shame on you !

Comment: We understand you're a new user; you're not banned from anything. Duarte corrected your mistake after it was correctly flagged. What's the problem? Also, I suggest you hold back on the name calling - it may make people less likely to help.

Comment: Thanks for your nice words, Ray,but I cancelled my account and I won't come back.